# Convert Windows formatted path to Unix style

Tags: unix, powershell, path

Suppose you have a path like so:

```
$myPath = 'C:\Python\27'
```

Is there a more reliable in PowerShell way of converting that path to Unix format than just replacing the `\`s like this?

```
PS C:\> $myPath -replace '\\','/'
C:/Python/27
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way I would do it, I'm not familiar with any other (built-in) way.