# changing windows path to unix path

Tags: powershell

I have a script which defines a variable $winpath with value "X:\data\tables\". This path value cannot be changed as it used by another function, but is it possible to translate/convert this value into a unix way (using some delimiters or any other methods?) and store in another variable? i.e /x/data/tables

```
$server = 10.1.1.1
$user = jason
$winpath = X:\data\tables\
Write-Output $user + '@' + $server + ':' + $winpath
```

Desired output-

```
jason@10.1.1.1/x/data/tables
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036140/powershell-convert-windows-formatted-path-to-unix-style

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```cs
$server = "10.1.1.1"
$user = "jason"
$winpath = "X:\data\tables\"

# replace backslashes with slashes, colons with nothing,
# convert to lower case and trim last /
$nixPath = (($winpath -replace "\\","/") -replace ":","").ToLower().Trim("/")

"$user@$server/$nixpath"
```

Variables are expanded in double quotes so you can directly build your string.